# Error installing gerrit: error: cannot start Gerrit: Gerrit is not initialized in /home/gerrit

Tags: java, ubuntu, gerrit

I'm having trouble installing Gerrit on my Linux server (Linux version 2.6.35-23-server Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5). This is what I get:

```
   john@test:/home/gerrit$ sudo jdk1.7.0_45/bin/java -jar gerrit-2.7.war init -
    d /home/gerrit/test_site

    *** Gerrit Code Review 2.7
    ***

    Create '/home/gerrit/test_site' [Y/n]?

    *** Git Repositories
    ***

    Location of Git repositories   [git]:

    *** SQL Database
    ***

    Database server type           [h2]:

    *** User Authentication
    ***

    Authentication method          [OPENID/?]:

    *** Email Delivery
    ***

    SMTP server hostname           [localhost]:
    SMTP server port               [(default)]:
    SMTP encryption                [NONE/?]:
    SMTP username                  :

    *** Container Process
    ***

    Run as                         [root]:
    Java runtime                   [/home/gerrit/jdk1.7.0_45/jre]:
    Copy gerrit.war to /home/gerrit/test_site/bin/gerrit.war [Y/n]? Y
    Copying gerrit.war to /home/gerrit/test_site/bin/gerrit.war

    *** SSH Daemon
    ***

    Listen on address              [*]:
    Listen on port                 [29418]:

    Gerrit Code Review is not shipped with Bouncy Castle Crypto v144
      If available, Gerrit can take advantage of features
      in the library, but will also function without it.
    Download and install it now [Y/n]?
    Downloading http://www.bouncycastle.org/download/bcprov-jdk16-144.jar ... OK
    Checksum bcprov-jdk16-144.jar OK
    Generating SSH host key ... rsa... dsa... done

    *** HTTP Daemon
    ***

    Behind reverse proxy           [y/N]?
    Use SSL (https://)             [y/N]?
    Listen on address              [*]: localhost
    Listen on port                 [8080]:
    Canonical URL                  [http://localhost:8080/]:

    *** Plugins
    ***

    Prompt to install core plugins [y/N]?

    Initialized /home/gerrit/test_site
    Executing /home/gerrit/test_site/bin/gerrit.sh start
    ** ERROR: Gerrit is not initialized in /home/gerrit
    error: cannot start Gerrit: exit status 1
    Waiting for server on localhost:8080 ... OK
    Opening http://localhost:8080/#/admin/projects/ ...OK
```

I then cannot access localhost:8080 (404 not found). Does anyone recognize this Gerrit initialization error? /var/log/apache2/error.log doesn't show anything relevant.

Comment: Anything in `/home/gerrit/test_site/logs/error_log`? Port 8080 is not yet in use, isn't it? (Although I would expect a different error message then..)

Comment: No, nothing there; that directory exists but there are no files there, error_log or otherwise. 8080 is open with a service of http-proxy. However netstat -tulpn showed mysqld listening on 8080...could this be preventing Gerrit from initialising properly?

Comment: Why do you specify the whole java path? Why do you use sudo? Is there an access right problem with the files?

Comment: Sorry, I've now added java to the path so now I don't have to specify the whole path. I've tried running as root or john; both the owner and group of the gerrit war file are john.